# How do I call a web page from an SQL Stored Proc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to write a sqlserver stored procedure that calls a web page, but I cant figure out how to do this.

Does anyone have an example?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide any more details on why you would want to do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: This seems like a very silly idea - no matter how it is accomplished. Web pages are for users to see on a monitor they are not web *services* designed to be called from applications.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is if you are using CLR integration

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3821271/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-within-SQL-Server.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very bad design to run external programs from `SQL Server`
However, you could use extended procedure `xp_cmdshell` to open a web browser with parameter.

```
 EXEC xp_cmdshell 
      '"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" http://www.bing.com'
```

Be aware that it will execute Internet Explorer on the db server. I am not sure if it is what you want. It will also block the rest of the script from running until the IE process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using a [CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx), I think you're out of luck.

I would also question what you're doing with the markup you get back from fetching the web page....

Comment: You know, there are web requests that don't return markup. In fact, I've heard there are web requests that don't return anything at all!

Comment: actually is more of a restful web service that I need to call, I don't need to capture the return.

Comment: @bzlm - I know web requests can return just about anything...but the OP specifically says "Web Page".

Answer (score 0):

SQL CLR is the easiest way to perform and HTTP Get request from a SQL Server stored procedure, as noted by other responses to this question. If you want something more robust, I would recommend you take a look at the [Service Broker External Activator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/36a58004-dbef-46ad-85a2-93563f3f8f0e/).